# Using Beautiful soup to analyze table in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I've got a table:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <caption></caption>
  <col>
  <col>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Pig</td>
  <td>House Type</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig A</td>
  <td>Straw</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig B</td>
  <td>Stick</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig C</td>
  <td>Brick</td>
</tr>
```

And I was simply trying to return a JSON string of the table pairs like so:

```
[["Pig A", "Straw"], ["Pig B", "Stick"], ["Pig C", "Brick"]]
```

However, with my code I can't seem to get rid of the HTML tags:

```
stable = soup.find('table')

cells = [ ]
rows = stable.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows[1:4]:
    # Process the body of the table
    row = []
    td = tr.findAll('td')
    #td = [el.text for el in soup.tr.finall('td')]
    row.append( td[0])
    row.append( td[1])
    cells.append( row )


return cells
```

#eventually, I'd like to do this:
    #h = json.dumps(cells)
    #return h

My output is this:

`[[<td>Pig A</td>, <td>Straw</td>], [<td>Pig B</td>, <td>Stick</td>], [<td>Pig C</td>, <td>Brick</td>]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `text` property to get only the inner text of the element:

```
row.append(td[0].text)
row.append(td[1].text)
```

Comment: first one worked.  second one gave me `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'contents'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lxml library.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import lxml.html as PARSER

#data = open('example.html').read() # You can read it from a html file.
#OR
data = """
<table border="1" style="width: 100%">
  <caption></caption>
  <col>
  <col>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Pig</td>
  <td>House Type</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig A</td>
  <td>Straw</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig B</td>
  <td>Stick</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pig C</td>
  <td>Brick</td>
</tr>
"""
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
main_list = []

for ele in root.getiterator():
    if ele.tag == "tr":
        text = ele.text_content().strip().split('\n')
        main_list.append(text)

print main_list
```

Output:
[['Pig', '  House Type'], ['Pig A', '  Straw'], ['Pig B', '  Stick'], ['Pig C', ' Brick']]